# How do I connect outside shower drain to storm water drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower, pipe-fitting

I have an outside shower and its drain is connected to a dry well. Since we use this shower frequently when returning to the beach and it backs up quickly with the dry well (maybe 2-3 minutes in the shower), I wanted to connect it to the storm drain.

The shower drain to dry well and storm drain run parallel to each other. My initial thought is to put an elbow after the shower drain (before the dry well) and divert it to the storm water pipe. I was planning to use a fitting to connect to the storm water (not sure which to use).

[image]

What's the best way to divert the water to the storm drain? What fitting would you recommend to connect into the storm drain?

Comment: Ask your local city/town about it.  My town gets down right picky if sump pumps are connected(or is that sewer pipe, have neither).  Storm drains are city owned, they .might want to know about extra connections

Comment: Is it a storm drain or sewer pipe from your house?  You might own/control the sewer pipe to the street.  Sewer pipe connections require a P-trap to prevent sewer gas from coming back up.  Storm drains are only for ground/road run off.

Comment: Yes, I own sewer and storm drain. City requires outside showers to drain to the street (ie storm drain). 

Any suggestions on fittings to divert from shower to storm drain?

Comment: You want to know the size of the shower drain pipe and the size of the storm drain pipe.  An elbow at the shower and a wye at the storm drain, the wye might need to be a reducing one, size of the storm drain to the size of the shower pipes.  Need about a 1/4 inch slope per foot from the shower to storm.

Comment: How are we supposed to know?  How far is the storm drain?  Is in in public ROW?  Why can't you just build a gutter from the shower to the storm drain?

Comment: The storm drain is 2 feet from the shower and runs along the side of the property. It’s a long pipe that runs to the curb. An elbow to a wye makes sense for the connection.