# Will this work? Shower drain to Flow Well to Storm Drain

Tags: shower, drain, drainage

My outside shower drain runs 12 feet to a dry well. It backs up after a minute or two after showering. I'm looking at other options and would appreciate any feedback. I have several neighbors with outside showers and they run their shower water to the storm drain.

1 - Place a Flow Well in the current dry well. Connect the shower drain pipe to it. Then, run a second pipe off a punch out near the top of the Flow Well that runs to the storm drain pipe.

2 - Dig underneath the cement shower drain slab and connect the pipe to the storm drain pipe. My concern is that this will be tricky with the cement slab and I'm concerned that we'd need to (possibly) break up the cement to do it. Thus, my slight preference for #1.

I don't think I can intercept the pipe that runs to the dry well as a connection point because it seems lower than the storm drain pipe. That's why I'm looking at these other options.

Comment: #1 should work.  #2 might be hard since if the two slopes are the same, you might have a similar problem of being too low at the shower also.  As your earlier question stated this is legal to do where you are.

Comment: #0 - clean out the dry well.

Comment: Why is the dry well backing up and why then wouldn't the FLow Well also back up?  If the simple reason is it has greater capacity, how much greater?  Because you're only getting 1 or 2 minutes is it 10 times the size?  In which case, I would think you would mention that.

Comment: Or wait ... is your dry well percolating into the surrounding ground but your Flow Well will flow to the storm sewers?  Is that even allowed?  Isn't the whole point of it to keep water out of the storm sewers?

Comment: Why would you put greywater into the storm sewer? Greywater needs to go to the correct drain so it gets treated.

Comment: @SolarMike in some places there is an exception (or a grandfathered one) for outdoor showers.  It doesn't make a lot of sense because some people will end up using the shower to wash their paint brushes or whatever ... but it exists.

Comment: @jay613 Yes, the code in my town is to drain an outside shower into the storm drain. And yes, when I had it built, I was trying to keep in on my property. I was hopeful that I would be able to use the water for irrigation at some point. I don't know why the dry well is backing up. I have pictures of how it was built...and it looks good.  My guess is that it isn't that big, so a 5-10 minute shower is too much for it. We often use it as an alternative to taking a shower after we return from the beach.

Comment: So the dry well was built expressly for the shower, and is not required or designed for storm water?  You should (have) put that in the question.  But in that case why do you need the Flow Well?  If you run a pipe from that location to the storm sewer why not just connect the pipe to the one from your shower? Or if you have the height problem as described, you need a pump ... is that the plan?  The FLow Well will be a sump pit for the shower ? Do you have electricity there?

Comment: Yes, the dry well was built for the shower.

I propose a Flow Well because it has knockouts and seems like an easy/clean way to connect the drain and outlet.

Yes, I don't think I will have the drop I need from drain from the shower drain to the storm drain. I'm hoping to find an easier solution before I have to dig and discover. II know I could chop up the concrete and solve my problem. I'm hoping to avoid this if possible.

No, I do not have a pump. Is that recommended? If so, any links to a recommended pump?

I have electricity 4 to 5 feet away.

Comment: Is this question different than your previous one? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/280605/how-do-i-connect-outside-shower-drain-to-storm-water-drain

Comment: @Huesmann I realized the drain drops 22" at the shower pad and that I can't connect directly to the storm unless I removed the cement shower pad. I am searching for an easier/better solution. I actually researched some sump gray water (sump basin) solutions online that look interesting. It would be great to use the water on nearby grass.